# How to merge two folders full of text files with matching names?

Tags: file, text, merge

Say I have the following:

```
C:/folder1/textfile1.txt
C:/folder1/textfile2.txt
C:/folder1/textfile3.txt

C:/folder2/textfile1.txt
C:/folder2/textfile2.txt
C:/folder2/textfile3.txt
```

I'd like to merge each file in folder2 with its matching file in folder1. If this is possible, how would I go about doing that? I've found a lot of stuff about merging a bunch of text files in a given folder into a single file, but nothing like this.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you should tell in which language you are willing to do that

Comment: Not much to go on here. No script/programming language specified. I presume windows batch files from the path names. Also you need to specifiy how you want to handle differences...

Comment: Command line I guess. I'm not trying to build software that does this or something, I just need to do it.